# bootstrap alert not show before redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

In my ajax response success I want to show my alert box first then after 5 second delay page will be reloaded.

I am using this code but nothing show in alert box.and alert box currently shown after page reload.

My code

```
success : function(data) {
    if(data.status == "success")
    {
        $(".flash_alert").html(data.msg);
        $('.flash_alert').delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
        location.reload();
    }
    else
    {
        bootbox.alert(data.msg);
    }
},
```

Alert box

```
<div class="flash_alert">

        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        </div>
</div>
```

alert box sown empty `$(".flash_alert").html(data.msg);` not work

also  `$('.flash_alert').delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");` not work before reload.

Actually I want after 5 sec shown alert box when alert box slid up then page will reload

Answer (score 0):

jquery's `fadeOut` gives a callback as second parameter which will run once the animation is complete so you want to reload after animation you could move `location.reload()` to this callback function:

```
$('.flash_alert')
  .delay(5000)
  .fadeOut("slow", function() {
    location.reload();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're **delaying** the hide action. But the control of the program **inmediatly** executes the next sentence `location.reload()`. So nothing happens. (Well it actually reloads the page immediately)

Instead, show your alert without any delay, and use

```
setTimeout(function(){
    location.reload();
}, 5000);
```

Or the `.delay()` approach to do this.